# Converting date from character to date format that can be used in a time series analysis in R

Tags: r, datetime, formatting, powerbi

I have a column in my data that has reported time as follows:

```
ID   country      Time
1      USA        March 18th 2020
2     Canada      April 21st 2020
3     Monaco      June  12th 2020
4     France      March 8th 2020
5     Italy       July 2nd 2020
```

The `time` column is in `character`. I wonder how I can convert it to `date format` that `R` and other software like `Power BI` and `Tableau` can understand the order of date as I want to use `Time` as a `factor` variable that has `ordinal` factors for my reporting. at this time, `Power BI` doesn't recognise the order of `date` in the `Time` column.

Comment: You don't have a year in the 'Time'

Comment: I just edited the data.Thanks!

Comment: I updated the post. please check

Comment: Thanks! my goal is to keep the dates in letter though not reported in number. Like `March 18th 2020` but in a date format that can be ordered both in R and other visualisation tools

Comment: in that case, create a new column with `Date` class and use that to order the rows

Comment: Thanks! I will try and keep you posted, just wondered if the order of `Date` will be recognised in Tableau.

Comment: If I remember, there are couple of formats the tableau would recognize.

Comment: Thanks, will be in touch, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to remove the substring at the end and then convert to `Date` class

```
df1$Date <- as.Date(sub("[a-z]+ (?=\\d{4}$)", " ", df1$Time, 
             perl = TRUE), "%B %d %Y")
```

Now, we can `order` the rows with `Date` column

```
df2 <- df1[order(df1$Date),]
```

---

Or another option is `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
mdy(df1$Time)
#[1] "2020-03-18" "2020-04-21" "2020-06-12" "2020-03-08" "2020-07-02"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, country = c("USA", "Canada", "Monaco", 
"France", "Italy"), Time = c("March 18th 2020", "April 21st 2020", 
"June  12th 2020", "March 8th 2020", "July 2nd 2020")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```